# Javascript regex not containing keyword with backslashes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having a problem with a javascript regex that has to comment out all  tags inside a script tag. But it can not comment out special first script tag with id "ignorescript".

Here is a sample string to regex:

```
<script id="ignorescript">
    var test = '<script>test<\/script>;
    var xxxx = 'x';
</script>
```

Script tag inside ignorescipt has extra backslash because it is JSON encoded (from PHP).

And here is the final result i have to get:

```
<script id="ignorescript">
    var test = '<!ignore-- <script>test<\/script> ignore-->;
    var xxxx = 'x';
</script>
```

Following example works:

```
content = content.replace(/(<script>.*<\\\/script>)/g,
    "<!--ignore $1 ignore-->");
```

But I need to check that it does not contain a keyword "ignorescript". If that keyword comes up then I do not want to replace anything. Otherwise add ignore comments to whole script tag So far I have gotten this far:

```
content = content.replace(/(<script.((?!ignorescript).)*<\/script>)/g,
    "<!--ignore $1 ignore-->");
```

It kinda works, but not the way it supposed to be. I also have one more backslash in ending tag. So I changed it to:

```
content = content.replace(/(<script.((?!ignorescript).)*<\\\/script>)/g,
    "<!--ignore $1 ignore-->");
```

Not it does not find anything at all.

Comment: I'm confused about your requirements. Shouldn't your example string not be replaced at all because the outermost script tag has 'ignorescript` as id? And why does one script tags have the extra backslash and not the other? Last, your last regex [is certainly replacing](http://regex101.com/r/wC3rU9).

Comment: One script has extra backslash because it is JSON encoded from PHP. Outermost script tag should not be commented out but script tag inside it should be.

Comment: Okay, could you put an example string on which your regex is not working? Maybe there's another condition you didn't explicitly mention.

Answer (score 0):

Got it finally working.

Here is the working regex:

```
/(<script(?!\sid="ignorescript").*?<\\\/script>)/g
```